# set CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX when using cpack

Tags: cmake, cpack

I am trying to create a rpm using cpack. The creating itself is ok, but I cannot make the install path to be correct.

In my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(ProjectName VERSION 1.2.3)

include(GNUInstallDirs) # << Here I use GNUInstallDirs for canonical install dir on linux

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

# next is just generating dummy code so that this example is standalone
add_custom_command(VERBATIM COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
                  COMMAND echo "int f(void) { return 0\; }" > ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dummy.cpp
                  COMMAND echo "dummy config" > ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/config.ini
                  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dummy.cpp ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/config.ini)
add_custom_target(gen
                 DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dummy.cpp ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/config.ini
                 OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dummy.cpp ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/config.ini)

add_library(dummy SHARED ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dummy.cpp)

set_target_properties(dummy  PROPERTIES
        VERSION "4"
        SOVERSION "4.1.2")

install(TARGETS dummy EXPORT MyLibraryConfig
    LIBRARY  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})

install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/config.ini DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR})
install(EXPORT MyLibraryConfig DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/MyLibrary/cmake)

include(cpack)
```

As stressed in code, I use GNUInstallDirs to have things installed correctly on linux, ie, when prefix is `/` or `/usr`, config stuff gos into `/etc` and libs in `/usr/lib`, when prefix is anything else, say /X, they go in `/X/etc/` and `/X/lib/`

This works fine when doing make install.

*BUT* I really cannot figure out how to set the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to / or /usr when invoking cpack, it seems to remain forever to /usr/local (default value) when it internaly calls the cmake command, despite the test I've done with:

```
CPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX 
CPACK_PACKAGING_PREFIX        
CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX 
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX         
CPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX        
CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY 
CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX 
CPACK_NATIVE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY
```

also messing around with `CPACK_SET_DESTDIR`.

I've never been able to get a rpm with the correct tree inside... I'm a bit puzzled.

commands I do are:

```
cmake . # generates the cpack stuff
cpack -G RPM # creates the rpm
rpm -q -l ProjectName-1.2.3-Linux.rpm # to check rpm content
```

and I get:

```
/usr/etc
/usr/etc/config.ini
/usr/lib/.build-id
/usr/lib/.build-id/f0
/usr/lib/.build-id/f0/9b19950e7734825f8d307f7835a8cc0e45c050
/usr/usr
/usr/usr/lib64
/usr/usr/lib64/libdummy.so
/usr/usr/lib64/libdummy.so.4
/usr/usr/lib64/libdummy.so.4.1.2
/usr/usr/share
/usr/usr/share/MyLibrary
/usr/usr/share/MyLibrary/cmake
/usr/usr/share/MyLibrary/cmake/MyLibraryConfig-relwithdebinfo.cmake
/usr/usr/share/MyLibrary/cmake/MyLibraryConfig.cmake
```

you may notice that the prefix seems to be usr here, but it was never passed to the cmake call actually (I put some print messages to make sure of it while debugging)

So what am I doing wrong? I there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the rpm generation does not compile anything. In the .spec file that the generator use (given in logs) it is actually spotted:

```
# This is a shortcutted spec file generated by CMake RPM generator
# we skip _install step because CPack does that for us.
# We do only save CPack installed tree in _prepr
# and then restore it in build.
%prep
mv $RPM_BUILD_ROOT %_topdir/tmpBBroot
```

so there is no compilation at this time, it just put into the package what is built by local directory, and here, the default value for prefix was because I did not set it up any CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX thinking the rpm generation would rebuild everything from scratch.

So the first solution is to call

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/ . before calling cpack.
```

Second solution (I think is better), is to generate a src.rpm and build the .rpm from this source rpm. I think this is better because it can be used to regenerate the rpm on any other update of the centos.

thus I added:

```
set(CPACK_RPM_SOURCE_PKG_BUILD_PARAMS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/)
```

to the CMakeLists.txt

and then created the src.rpm doing

```
cmake -DCPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_SOURCES=ON . && cpack -G RPM  --config CPackSourceConfig.cmake
```

then I get a projectname-1.2.3-1.src.rpm on which I can call rpmbuild:

```
rpmbuild --rebuild projectname-1.2.3-1.src.rpm
```

which generated a rpm which holds the binaries with the correct paths:

```
$ rpm -ql ProjectName-1.2.3-Linux.rpm 
/etc/config.ini
/usr/lib/.build-id
/usr/lib/.build-id/7e
/usr/lib/.build-id/7e/045303c53b44d5592555b4703b9783eaeb8f83
/usr/lib64/libdummy.so
/usr/lib64/libdummy.so.4
/usr/lib64/libdummy.so.4.1.2
/usr/share/MyLibrary
/usr/share/MyLibrary/cmake
/usr/share/MyLibrary/cmake/MyLibraryConfig-relwithdebinfo.cmake
/usr/share/MyLibrary/cmake/MyLibraryConfig.cmake
```